# Spring Boot Jackson serialization for List Object

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I have a List of "Personnel" objects List that I am returning from my Spring Boot ReST controller. The output is fine except for one issue.

This **Personnel** object has a **PersonnelType** object as one of it's nested objects.  When serializing the first Personnel object in the List, the entire sub-object of PersonnelType is serialized, which is what I want.

However, if the second or subsequent Personnel objects in the List have the same PersonnelType (same id) as the PersonnelType already serialized in the first Personnel object, these subsequent PersonnelType objects are being serialized with just an "id" and not the entire object.

For example, here is the serialized output:

```
[
    {
            "id": 2,
            "creatorUserId": null,
            "creationTime": null,
            "lastModifierUserId": null,
            "lastModificationTime": null,
            "workforceId": 9994323221,
            "workPhoneNumber": "7034563452",
            "workEmailAddress": "xxx@epa.gov",
            "currentPosition": "Developer",
            "isSponsored": false,
            "dateOfSponsorship": null,
            "sponsorPersonnelId": null,
            "isLEO": true,
            "isFERO": false,
            "requireComputerAndEmailAccess": true,
            "isPriorityCase": false,
            "building": {
                "id": 1,
                "creatorUserId": null,
                "creationTime": null,
                "lastModifierUserId": null,
                "lastModificationTime": null,
                "isActive": true,
                "buildingName": "Robert C Byrd Courthouse and FOB",
                "buildingNumber": "406",
                "displayGlobal": false,
                "facilityName": "Robert C Byrd Courthouse",
                "facilityNumber": "107",
                "handler": {},
                "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}
            },
            "personnelType": {
                "id": 1,
                "creatorUserId": null,
                "creationTime": null,
                "lastModifierUserId": null,
                "lastModificationTime": null,
                "description": "Federal Employee",
                "isActive": true,
                "handler": {},
                "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}
            }
    },

    {
            "id": 2,
            "creatorUserId": null,
            "creationTime": null,
            "lastModifierUserId": null,
            "lastModificationTime": null,
            "workforceId": 9994323221,
            "workPhoneNumber": "7034563452",
            "workEmailAddress": "xxx@epa.gov",
            "currentPosition": "Developer",
            "isSponsored": false,
            "dateOfSponsorship": null,
            "sponsorPersonnelId": null,
            "isLEO": true,
            "isFERO": false,
            "requireComputerAndEmailAccess": true,
            "isPriorityCase": false,
            "building": {
                "id": 1,
                "creatorUserId": null,
                "creationTime": null,
                "lastModifierUserId": null,
                "lastModificationTime": null,
                "isActive": true,
                "buildingName": "Robert C Byrd Courthouse and FOB",
                "buildingNumber": "406",
                "displayGlobal": false,
                "facilityName": "Robert C Byrd Courthouse",
                "facilityNumber": "107",
                "handler": {},
                "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}
            },
            "personnelType": 1          
    }

]
```

Above, the first Personnel object in the serialized List has the full object for PersonnelType serialized, whereas the second Personnel object in the serialized List has PersonnelType serialized ONLY as an id because the id for PersonnelType (id = 1) is the same as for PersonnelType in the first Personnel object in the List.

Is this the default behavior of the Jackson serializer?  I am not using @JsonIdentityReference and therefore by default it's false.

**@JsonIdentityReference
Marker to indicate whether all referenced values are to be serialized as ids (true); or by serializing the first encountered reference as POJO and only then as id (false).**

How can I change the serialization such that I return the full PersonnelType sub-object in every Personnel Object in the List (even though it has already been serialized once in a previous Personnel object in the List)?

Here is my Personnel entity with the annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Personnel", schema = "dbo", catalog = "PSSV2Db")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id",resolver = EntityIdResolver.class, scope = PersonnelEntity.class)

public class PersonnelEntity extends AuditedEntity<String> {

    private Long id;
    private Long workforceId;
    private String workPhoneNumber;
    private String workEmailAddress;
    private String UPN;
    private String currentPosition;
    private Boolean isSponsored;
    private LocalDate dateOfSponsorship;
    private String sponsorPersonnelId;
    private Boolean isLEO;
    private Boolean isFERO;
    private Boolean requireComputerAndEmailAccess;
    private Boolean isPriorityCase;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PersonnelId", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Basic
    @Column(name = "WorkforceId", nullable = false)
    public Long getWorkforceId() {
        return workforceId;
    }

    public void setWorkforceId(Long workforceId) {
        this.workforceId = workforceId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "WorkPhoneNumber", nullable = true)
    public String getWorkPhoneNumber() {
        return workPhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setWorkPhoneNumber(String workPhoneNumber) {
        this.workPhoneNumber = workPhoneNumber;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "WorkEmailAddress", nullable = true)
    public String getWorkEmailAddress() {
        return workEmailAddress;
    }

    public void setWorkEmailAddress(String workEmailAddress) {
        this.workEmailAddress = workEmailAddress;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "UPN", nullable = true)

    public String getUPN() {
        return UPN;
    }

    public void setUPN(String UPN) {
        this.UPN = UPN;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CurrentPosition", nullable = true)
    public String getCurrentPosition() {
        return currentPosition;
    }

    public void setCurrentPosition(String currentPosition) {
        this.currentPosition = currentPosition;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "IsSponsored", nullable = true)

    public Boolean getIsSponsored() {
        return isSponsored;
    }

    public void setIsSponsored(Boolean sponsored) {
        this.isSponsored = sponsored;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DateOfSponsorship", nullable = true)

    public LocalDate getDateOfSponsorship() {
        return dateOfSponsorship;
    }

    public void setDateOfSponsorship(LocalDate dateOfSponsorship) {
        this.dateOfSponsorship = dateOfSponsorship;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "SponsorPersonnelId", nullable = true)

    public String getSponsorPersonnelId() {
        return sponsorPersonnelId;
    }

    public void setSponsorPersonnelId(String sponsorPersonnelId) {
        this.sponsorPersonnelId = sponsorPersonnelId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "IsLEO", nullable = false)
    public Boolean getIsLEO() {
        return isLEO;
    }

    public void setIsLEO(Boolean LEO) {
        this.isLEO = LEO;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "IsFERO", nullable = false)

    public Boolean getIsFERO() {
        return isFERO;
    }

    public void setIsFERO(Boolean FERO) {
        this.isFERO = FERO;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "RequireComputerAndEmailAddress", nullable = false)

    public Boolean getRequireComputerAndEmailAccess() {
        return requireComputerAndEmailAccess;
    }

    public void setRequireComputerAndEmailAccess(Boolean requireComputerAndEmailAccess) {
        this.requireComputerAndEmailAccess = requireComputerAndEmailAccess;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "IsPriorityCase", nullable = false)
    public Boolean getIsPriorityCase() {
        return isPriorityCase;
    }

    public void setIsPriorityCase(Boolean isPriorityCase) {
        this.isPriorityCase = isPriorityCase;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof PersonnelEntity)) return false;
        PersonnelEntity that = (PersonnelEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId()) &&
                Objects.equals(getWorkforceId(), that.getWorkforceId()) &&
                Objects.equals(getWorkPhoneNumber(), that.getWorkPhoneNumber()) &&
                Objects.equals(getWorkEmailAddress(), that.getWorkEmailAddress()) &&
                Objects.equals(getUPN(), that.getUPN()) &&
                Objects.equals(getCurrentPosition(), that.getCurrentPosition()) &&
                Objects.equals(getIsSponsored(), that.getIsSponsored()) &&
                Objects.equals(getDateOfSponsorship(), that.getDateOfSponsorship()) &&
                Objects.equals(getSponsorPersonnelId(), that.getSponsorPersonnelId()) &&
                Objects.equals(getIsLEO(), that.getIsLEO()) &&
                Objects.equals(getIsFERO(), that.getIsFERO()) &&
                Objects.equals(getRequireComputerAndEmailAccess(), that.getRequireComputerAndEmailAccess()) &&
                Objects.equals(getIsPriorityCase(), that.getIsPriorityCase());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(getId(), getWorkforceId(), getWorkPhoneNumber(), getWorkEmailAddress(), getUPN(), getCurrentPosition(), getIsSponsored(), getDateOfSponsorship(), getSponsorPersonnelId(), getIsLEO(), getIsFERO(), getRequireComputerAndEmailAccess(), getIsPriorityCase());
    }


    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BuildingId")
    public BuildingsEntity getBuilding() {
        return building;
    }
    public void setBuilding(BuildingsEntity building) {
        this.building = building;
    }

    private BuildingsEntity building;




    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PersonnelTypeId")
    public PersonnelTypesEntity getPersonnelType() {
        return personnelType;
    }
    public void setPersonnelType(PersonnelTypesEntity personnelType) {
        this.personnelType = personnelType;
    }

    private PersonnelTypesEntity personnelType;


}
```

Here is the PersonnelType entity with annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PersonnelTypes", schema = "dbo", catalog = "PSSV2Db")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", resolver = EntityIdResolver.class, scope = PersonnelTypesEntity.class)

public class PersonnelTypesEntity extends AuditedEntity<String> {
    private long id;
    private String description;
    private Boolean isActive;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PersonnelTypeId", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Description", nullable = true, length = 8000)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "IsActive", nullable = false)
    public Boolean getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(Boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof PersonnelTypesEntity)) return false;
        PersonnelTypesEntity that = (PersonnelTypesEntity) o;
        return getId() == that.getId() &&
                Objects.equals(getDescription(), that.getDescription()) &&
                Objects.equals(getIsActive(), that.getIsActive());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(getId(), getDescription(), getIsActive());
    }
}
```

Comment: no this is not the default

Comment: can you post Personnel and PersonnelType class with all the annotations that you have applied.

Comment: I added them above

Comment: you are using JsonIdentityInfo. Look at its docs

Answer (score 0):

I used the JSOG library to provide @id and @ref to all the serialized output and the API consumer will also need to use the JSOG library to convert back and get the full object graph on the client.

This seems like such a common problem, yet Jackson does not provide a solution natively.